# How to populate DesignData on Xamarin.Android app

Tags: c#, android, wpf, xaml, xamarin.android

Is there a way to apply `DesignData` - like `WPF` - to a control in a (`Xamarin.`)`Android` control?

In WPF I just have to make a new *.xaml file, make my XAML Code like

```
<vm:PersonViewModel
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel"
    xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:MyProject.Model>
    <Model:Person ID="1" FirstName="John" LastName="Doe" />
    <Model:Person ID="2" FirstName="Liz" LastName="Fisher" />
</PersonViewModel>
```

reference the XAML file in my View

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/SampleData/SampleData.xaml}"
```

and Done.
Is there a way to do similliar things in AXML with Android?

Comment: Couldn't find anything for Xamarin.Android, just for Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html Maybe with the tool namespace from Android. This should work.